# How many configurations are in a 16 by 16 grid filled with colors?

Tags: permutations

What I am asking is the amt of possible configurations of a 16x16 sprite?

I tried doing the following by myself I just want to know if I'm correct.

I think if I have RGB as color it would be $256 \cdot 256 \cdot 256$ which is $256^3$ or
$16777216$.
Then to calculate the combinations of something is. The configurations raised to the power of how many there are.
So since there are $16 \times 16$ grid or $256$.
We get

$16777216^{256}$ or $(256 ^ 3) ^ {16 \times 16}$.

I used this to do it:
https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm

Am I right about this?

Comment: You are right, but I fail to see why this is useful? The vast majority of such combinations aren't particularly interesting.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I was right. Okay I'll accept Brian's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. More tersely, you have $(256^3)^{256} = 256^{768} = 2^{6144}$ permutations. The decimal representation of this number is generally of little interest. It suffices to note that this number is **big**. For some perspective on just how unfathomably humongous this number is, consider viewing [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9JGmA5_unY) on how "big" $2^{256}$ is.